# how to get the height one div and assign it to other div, after html finishes rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
<div class="col-xs-10" id="leftDoc" "> ... </div>
  <uib-tabset type="tabs">
      <uib-tab heading="Event 1 Information"> ....
      <uib-tab heading="Event 2 Information"> ....
      <uib-tab heading="Event 3 Information"> ....
      <uib-tab heading="Event 3 Information"> ....
  </uib-tabset>
<div class="col-xs-10" id="leftDoc" > ... </div>
```

basically i have angular app i just want to get height from "leftDoc" and assign it to "rightDoc". there seems to be discussion about this topic but its related to controller finishing loading data, but in my case i don't have any data to load from, but when i use this script, it calculates the wrong height

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var height = Math.max($("#leftDoc").height(), $("#rightDoc").height());
      $("#leftDoc").height(height);
      $("#rightDoc").height(height);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it adding the padding height too?

Comment: not sure if i can tell

Comment: Is it about 32px higher on one side?

Comment: nope more like 300px

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var leftHeight = $( "#leftDoc" ).height();

    $( "#rightDoc" ).height( leftHeight );
} );
```

Or

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var leftHeight = $( "#leftDoc" ).height();

    $( "#rightDoc" ).css( "height", leftHeight );
} );
```

**Edit:**

You can also use [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) to include the div's top and bottom padding:

`var leftHeight = $( "#leftDoc" ).outerHeight();`